# Twilio Conversation on Xamarin, send Message

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, twilio

I am trying to send a message through Twilio Conversation in Xamarin by [Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin](https://github.com/jedusei/Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin).

How can I send a new message? There is `IConversation.SendMessageAsync()` method but it takes `IMessageOption` interface and I honestly do not know what kind of implementation is needed.

Read many hours in Google but it does not help for me.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a question in [github](https://github.com/jedusei/Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin/issues/2) and @slimethefrozen helped how to do that in Twilio.Conversations.Xamarin.

Here is his answer.

I use this to create the IMessageOption on iOS

```
var options = new TCHMessageOptions().WithBody(body);
```

Where body is the text of the message.

On Android I use this:

```
var options = IMessage.Options().WithBody(body);
```

**Updated:**
As version 2.0.0, the code to send a message is below.

```
var clientInstance; // Create an instance for IConversationsClient

await .PrepareMessage().SetBody(messageBody).BuildAndSendAsync(new());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Android version of sending a message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/android/exploring-conversations-android-quickstart?code-sample=code-sending-a-message-to-a-conversation&code-language=Android%20-%20Java&code-sdk-version=default) you create a `Message.Options` object as a builder that you add a body to, like this:

```java
Message.Options options = Message.options().withBody(messageBody);
```

In the [iOS version](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/ios/exploring-conversations-swift-quickstart?code-sample=code-sending-a-message-to-a-conversation&code-language=Swift&code-sdk-version=default) you create a [`TCHMessageOptions`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/conversations/releases/2.2.2/docs/Classes/TCHMessageOptions.html) object which is a builder that you add a body to, like this:

```swift
let messageOptions = TCHMessageOptions().withBody(messageText)
```

I'm not sure how Xamarin or the bindings work, but it looks like you will need to create an object that has a body property to fulfil the interface.